# Excel DNA - Best Way to Use Config Transforms

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I have a project, lets call it 'ProjectX' which needs to use Excel DNA. Development is successful, however, I am unable to resolve one issue. The project uses config transforms to update values in app.config when building for different environments, for example DEV, UAT, and PROD.

**Here is the issue:** When I build for a certain environment, like DEV, the `app.config` transforms as expected. However, `ProjectX-AddIn64-packed.xll.config` does NOT transform, and this is the config that Excel DNA is using inside the XLL. I'm not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated.

**Constraints:** I can only deploy **one** file, the XLL.

**Things I Have Tried/Researched:**

1. Renaming `app.config` to `ProjectX-AddIn64-packed.xll.config`
2. Using Visual Studio Build Events
3. Editing `ExcelDna.Build.props` to try and override the default build/packaging process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.config transforms are currently not supported in Excel-DNA, as of this writing. One workaround at the moment is to replace the `.xll.config` files with the contents of the `.dll.config` file at the end of the build, after the transformation has been applied.

There are many different ways you can choose to do this file replacement... For example, you can run a script in a post-build event, or alternatively add a new MSBuild target to your `.csproj` file that runs after the `ExcelDnaBuild` task which copies the file(s).

E.g.

```
<Target Name="CopyAppConfig" AfterTargets="ExcelDnaBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)MyAddIn-AddIn.xll.config" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)MyAddIn-AddIn-packed.xll.config" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)MyAddIn-AddIn64.xll.config" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)MyAddIn-AddIn64-packed.xll.config" />
</Target>
```

You can read more about this on our GitHub repo:

- [Hard coded references to App.config prevents use of config transforms in build. #282](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/282)
- [AutoGenerateBindingRedirects doesn't work properly #241](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/241)

Comment: @C Augusto, I muct have finally type the right words into Google because I found this exact answer elsewhere, and it was your answer as well! Great solution, I can confirm this did work as advertised. Much thanks! For others looking at this answer, check out the original Google Group for some more info. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/exceldna/MXybGyrLe9Q/CtDoFdEXCQAJ